# How can I monitor a mariadb instance with newrelic?

Tags: mariadb, newrelic-platform

How can I monitor a mariadb instance with the New Relic MySQL plugin?

I can monitor mysql 5.1.  I can talk to the mariadb 5.5 db with the mysql cli.  But when I try to talk to mariadb 5.5 with the newrelic mysql plugin, I get this:

> [2014-01-14 16:27:43 -0800]
>   com.newrelic.metrics.publish.binding.Context | SEVERE | Unable to
>   obtain a new database connection: jdbc:mysql://db001:10017/
>   newrelic/PASSWORD_FILTERED, check your MySQL configuration settings.
>   Could not create connection to database server.

Comment: Newrelic has adopted this as a feature request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New Relic doesn't officially support MariaDB, but it may work. The New Relic plugin requires that it can connect via TCP. You can test this by trying to connect locally over TCP.

For mysql you would run something like: `mysql -u newrelic -pPASSWORD -hHOST --protocol=TCP`

The JDBC drivers that work with MySQL may not work the same way which could mean that this plugin will not work correctly with MariaDB.

Comment: I can definitely connect with the mysql client via tcp.  Any idea how to make the newrelic client talk to mariadb?  Is it a simple matter of unpacking the jar and replacing the connector/j it comes with, with mariadb's jdbc driver?

Comment: I would love to know if anyone has any success with this -- I inherited several MariaDB instances and would love to get them monitored.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and thought it was a MariaDB issue. It turns out I had installed Java 1.5 (the default if you do yum install java). Once I switched to 1.6 it started working.